# Error in paypal login with sandbox test credential

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

[image]*

Hi , I am integrated paypal mpl gateway in my android project , and created sandbox test credential but whenever  i want to login with these credential it always shows " This  app contains payment capabilities that aren't compatible with your device  "
  *

Comment: have you get any solution for it ?

Comment: no, currently i haven't any solution for this.

Comment: Same here. Real live credentials doe not work for sandbox PayPal login testing